# iTunes U with non-Apple devices

Tags: itunes, itunes-u

Is it possible to sync iTunes U feeds with non-Apple devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download classes from iTunes U, there are stored on your computer hard drive. Then You can handle those files to be sync with the device you think about, with the tool you uselaly use... There no big difference.

Answer (score 0):

[Isyncr](http://jrtstudio.com/) allows syncing of iTunes (including iTunes U) with Android